# How do I redirect to the same controller-action in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application I need to redirect to the same controller-action pair with some specific parameters. I use this:

```
return RedirectToAction((String)RouteData.Values["action"],
    new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 } );
```

and it works but I have to carry this rather inelegant code around when I want to reuse it.

I could of course craft a helper or something but I hoped there's something ready in the framework.

Is there perhaps some more elegant and reuse-friendly way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass `null` as the action name:

```
return RedirectToAction(null, new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 } );
```

Internally, `RedirectToAction` is is calling the `RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues()` helper method that will try to merge new route values (including the action) with existing route data that is already available on controller initialization. So, if `action` is null, the `MergeRouteValues` would return the current action as you wish.

You may want to to replace `null` with more explicit construct that will clearly express your intent:

```
private const string SAME_ACTION = null;
// then
return RedirectToAction(SAME_ACTION, new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 } );
```

See [Controller.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L512) (line 512) and [RouteValuesHelpers.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteValuesHelpers.cs#L48) (line 49)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a strongly typed `RedirectToAction` from [MvcContrib](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction&referringTitle=Documentation). I've used it all the time with ASP.NET MVC and I'm quite happy with.

```
public ActionResult RedirectActionOnSameController()
{
    return this.RedirectToAction(c => c.Index());
}
```